# Navigation drawer Kotlin/Android studio not showing on activity

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, navigation-drawer

I am trying to show a navigation drawer in an activity using android studio(arctic ice) and kotlin. When I try this code in a new project with only one activity (main activity) it works fine.  If I copy and paste the same code in my project, the activity shows up but without the app bar/action bar/navigation drawer. My project has multiple activities and I call the final activity with navigation bar from the startup activity.

Kotlin activity code

```
class LandingPage : AppCompatActivity() {
lateinit var toggle: ActionBarDrawerToggle

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_landing_page)

    val drawerLayout: DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
    val navView: NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

    toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close)

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
    toggle.syncState()

    supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

    navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
        when (it.itemId) {
            R.id.firstmenu -> Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()


        }
        true
    }

}
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

NAV-HEADER.XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"


>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textStyle="bold">

</TextView>
```

nav_menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:showIn="navigation_view">
<item
    android:id="@+id/firstmenu"
    android:title="First"></item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/secondmenu"
    android:title="Second"></item>
<item
    android:id="@+id/thirdmenu"
    android:title="Third"></item>
```

landingpage.xml (activity)

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".LandingPage">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ACTIVITY 2"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </TextView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/nav_menu">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
```

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

What Could I be doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: It could be a typo in the question but I notice you do `setContentView` with `activity_landing_page` while you say your activity is named`landingpage.xml`. So that would mean you need to do `setContentView(R.layout.landingpage)` instead

Comment: Thanks for reading through and replying. What you pointed out is NOT the case. I am extremely sorry for misleading you. It was <parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"> in Res-->Values-->Themes-->themes.xml that was the problem. Changing it to <parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"> solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It was <parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar"> in Res-->Values-->Themes-->themes.xml that was the problem. Changing it to <parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"> solved the issue.